# Cannot Find Gem IO-Console

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems

When I run `gem search -l -d` I get io-console included in my list

```
io-console (0.4.5)
    Author: Nobu Nakada
    Homepage: http://www.ruby-lang.org
    License: BSD-2-Clause
    Installed at (default): /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0

Console interface
```

However, when I run `ls -la /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0`, no folder or file called io-console exists in that directory or in the /gems directory within it. Where is this gem located?

Comment: If I install it manually `gem install io-console` it shows up in there.

I have also been able to determine it was installed as a dependency of pry for me

Comment: It was showing up in my gem list before I installed anything (this is on a freshly installed OS w/no previous user data)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This gem comes pre-installed with Ruby itself. It is one of the core libraries and is not actually installed as Ruby code but a shared library:

```
Gem.find_files('io/console')
=> ["/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.5.0/io/console.so"]
```

Comment: Interesting that it shows up as a "gem" then. My understanding of gems is that they were like libraries *external* to the language that could be installed with RubyGems, not something core to the language.

Comment: @stk1234 It's a good question. I don't know the specific logistics for core inclusion in this case. It seems you could actually upgrade this library if you want to, without installing a newer Ruby version, since it's indeed available on RubyGems separately.